# Hosting Microsoft Office application inside Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, com-interop

I know that Silverlight 4 has support for COM interop via the `AutomationFactory` class.

```
dynamic excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject( "Excel.Application" );
excel.Visible = true;
```

But this creates a separate window for the COM object. What I am missing here is if I am actually able to actually host an Office document inside my Silverlight application - in a ContentPresenter for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing anything - it can't be done. You could look for converters to Silverlight of Office documents like

- [TextGlow](http://www.textglow.com) for Word (source is on
  [CodePlex](http://textglow.codeplex.com/)) (2007 [*and maybe
  2010*] format only).
- PowerPoint to Silverlight
  Convertor (client side conversion,
  requires PowerPoint to be installed),
  also on [CodePlex](http://pptx2silverlight.codeplex.com/).

Both of these are view-only and do not come close to full fidelity - but they are a "good enough" set of options.

Comment: Would be really neat if we could host office inside our containers, wouldn't it? Anyway, thanks for the information!