# What are the limitations of silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

What is the significance of Silverlight out of browser mode in terms of installation, privileges, restrictions and updates?

Is it possible to run Silverlight(in browser mode, within web pages) in full screen mode (like when pressing F11 key )? What are the restrictions? Is it possible immediately after  uploading the application?

Is it possible to run office(word,excel)  through Silverlight in out of browser mode or in browser mode(within web pages)?

Is it possible to capture the event of closing the browser in silverlight?

Comment: All of this is answered if you simply read the Silverlight doco. I'm voting to close this because it appears you've put no effort into researching this before popping out the questions.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx for a description of trusted applications which have elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to run Silverlight in full screen mode. You can use F11 key for that. You may use the following code for running Silverlight in full screen mode.

```
private void btnFullScreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnFullScreen.IsChecked.Value)
    {
          Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = true;                                
          btnFullScreen.Content = "Exit Full Screen";
    }
    else {
        Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = false;
        btnFullScreen.Content = "Full Screen";
    }
 }
```

Secondly, it is not yet possible to run/host MS Office programs through Silverlight. See the link below for further info about this:

[Hosting Microsoft Office application inside Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888675/hosting-microsoft-office-application-inside-silverlight-4)

Finally, you can implement the capturing the event of closing the browser in Silverlight by calling a JavaScript `OnClose()` method from Silverlight.

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43157/Calling-Web-Services-from-Silverlight-after-the-Br) for the information about capturing the event of browser closing in Silverlight.